# escaping curly braces for string.format

Tags: c#

```
void f(string message)
{
    string.Format(message,"x",y");
}
```

f() is called by g:

```
g()
{
   f(SomeJson+"{0}");
}
```

the curly braces in json are being interpreted as placeholders for values by `string.format()` in f().
IS there a way to have the curly braces escaped?

Comment: It's hard to be sure, but I suspect his question is slightly different to the suggested duplicate. He wants to escape the characters in a generated string, not the string literal he has used.

Comment: Just append the formatted string to `SomeJson` **after** formatting.

Answer (score 9):

Double them up:

```
f(SomeJson+"{{0}}");
```

Or replace them in the JSON, if that's what you need:

```
f(SomeJson.Replace("{", "{{")
    .Replace("}", "}}") + "{0}");
```

You could also delegate this job to an extension method:

```
public static class StringExtensions
{
    public static string EscapeBraces(this string s)
    {
        return s.Replace("{", "{{")
                .Replace("}", "}}");
    }
}

f(SomeJson.EscapeBraces() + "{0}");
```

Or, as Ergwun says, you could simply concatenate the values afterwards. My assumption, though, is that that's less straightforward in your actual code than in this trivial example.

Comment: If it is the braces in the JSON that he wants to escape, he's actually better off concatenating the strings after he has performed the variable substitutions. No escaping required.

Comment: @Ergwun Very true. Unless, of course, `f` is less trivial than he's making out.

Comment: Yeah, the fact he has a single substitution, but two parameters in the code in his question does open that possibility. But if he's generating format strings from JSON, then that's a whole separate problem!